# Visual Studio Team Explorer - GIT: Automatically ignoring new files

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, team-explorer

Whenever I create a new file such as a class file (.cs), the file is automatically ignored by GIT (although still included in the project). Is it something with my .gitignore file or some Visual Studio setting? A bug?

Interestingly, I have 7 projects under my solution and only 1 project has this behavior.

**Why do I think it's ignored and not untracked? Here's the answer:**

1- Normally Visual Studio will track all new .cs files, that's what it does in all my projects except for this one.

2- The new file's Version Control Status Icon is a red circle (with a rectangle in the middle), which if hovered over will show the word "Ignored". In addition, if I right click on the file I can see the option "Add Ignored File to Source Control."

Here's the .gitignore file (on the same folder as that of the .git folder):

```
## Ignore Visual Studio temporary files, build results, and
## files generated by popular Visual Studio add-ons.
##
## Get latest from https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore

# User-specific files
*.suo
*.user
*.userosscache
*.sln.docstates

# User-specific files (MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio)
*.userprefs

# Build results
[Dd]ebug/
[Dd]ebugPublic/
[Rr]elease/
[Rr]eleases/
x64/
x86/
bld/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/
[Ll]og/

# Visual Studio 2015 cache/options directory
.vs/
.vscode/
# Uncomment if you have tasks that create the project's static files in wwwroot
#wwwroot/

# MSTest test Results
[Tt]est[Rr]esult*/
[Bb]uild[Ll]og.*

# NUNIT
*.VisualState.xml
TestResult.xml

# Build Results of an ATL Project
[Dd]ebugPS/
[Rr]eleasePS/
dlldata.c

# .NET Core
project.lock.json
project.fragment.lock.json
artifacts/
**/Properties/launchSettings.json

*_i.c
*_p.c
*_i.h
*.ilk
*.meta
*.obj
*.pch
*.pdb
*.pgc
*.pgd
*.rsp
*.sbr
*.tlb
*.tli
*.tlh
*.tmp
*.tmp_proj
*.log
*.vspscc
*.vssscc
.builds
*.pidb
*.svclog
*.scc

# Chutzpah Test files
_Chutzpah*

# Visual C++ cache files
ipch/
*.aps
*.ncb
*.opendb
*.opensdf
*.sdf
*.cachefile
*.VC.db
*.VC.VC.opendb

# Visual Studio profiler
*.psess
*.vsp
*.vspx
*.sap

# TFS 2012 Local Workspace
$tf/

# Guidance Automation Toolkit
*.gpState

# ReSharper is a .NET coding add-in
_ReSharper*/
*.[Rr]e[Ss]harper
*.DotSettings.user

# JustCode is a .NET coding add-in
.JustCode

# TeamCity is a build add-in
_TeamCity*

# DotCover is a Code Coverage Tool
*.dotCover

# Visual Studio code coverage results
*.coverage
*.coveragexml

# NCrunch
_NCrunch_*
.*crunch*.local.xml
nCrunchTemp_*

# MightyMoose
*.mm.*
AutoTest.Net/

# Web workbench (sass)
.sass-cache/

# Installshield output folder
[Ee]xpress/

# DocProject is a documentation generator add-in
DocProject/buildhelp/
DocProject/Help/*.HxT
DocProject/Help/*.HxC
DocProject/Help/*.hhc
DocProject/Help/*.hhk
DocProject/Help/*.hhp
DocProject/Help/Html2
DocProject/Help/html

# Click-Once directory
publish/

# Publish Web Output
*.[Pp]ublish.xml
*.azurePubxml
# TODO: Comment the next line if you want to checkin your web deploy settings
# but database connection strings (with potential passwords) will be unencrypted
*.pubxml
*.publishproj

# Microsoft Azure Web App publish settings. Comment the next line if you want to
# checkin your Azure Web App publish settings, but sensitive information contained
# in these scripts will be unencrypted
PublishScripts/

# NuGet Packages
*.nupkg
# The packages folder can be ignored because of Package Restore
**/packages/*
# except build/, which is used as an MSBuild target.
!**/packages/build/
# Uncomment if necessary however generally it will be regenerated when needed
#!**/packages/repositories.config
# NuGet v3's project.json files produces more ignorable files
*.nuget.props
*.nuget.targets

# Microsoft Azure Build Output
csx/
*.build.csdef

# Microsoft Azure Emulator
ecf/
rcf/

# Windows Store app package directories and files
AppPackages/
BundleArtifacts/
Package.StoreAssociation.xml
_pkginfo.txt

# Visual Studio cache files
# files ending in .cache can be ignored
*.[Cc]ache
# but keep track of directories ending in .cache
!*.[Cc]ache/

# Others
ClientBin/
~$*
*~
*.dbmdl
*.dbproj.schemaview
*.jfm
*.pfx
*.publishsettings
orleans.codegen.cs

# Since there are multiple workflows, uncomment next line to ignore bower_components
# (https://github.com/github/gitignore/pull/1529#issuecomment-104372622)
#bower_components/

# RIA/Silverlight projects
Generated_Code/

# Backup & report files from converting an old project file
# to a newer Visual Studio version. Backup files are not needed,
# because we have git ;-)
_UpgradeReport_Files/
Backup*/
UpgradeLog*.XML
UpgradeLog*.htm

# SQL Server files
*.mdf
*.ldf
*.ndf

# Business Intelligence projects
*.rdl.data
*.bim.layout
*.bim_*.settings

# Microsoft Fakes
FakesAssemblies/

# GhostDoc plugin setting file
*.GhostDoc.xml

# Node.js Tools for Visual Studio
.ntvs_analysis.dat
node_modules/

# Typescript v1 declaration files
typings/

# Visual Studio 6 build log
*.plg

# Visual Studio 6 workspace options file
*.opt

# Visual Studio 6 auto-generated workspace file (contains which files were open etc.)
*.vbw

# Visual Studio LightSwitch build output
**/*.HTMLClient/GeneratedArtifacts
**/*.DesktopClient/GeneratedArtifacts
**/*.DesktopClient/ModelManifest.xml
**/*.Server/GeneratedArtifacts
**/*.Server/ModelManifest.xml
_Pvt_Extensions

# Paket dependency manager
.paket/paket.exe
paket-files/

# FAKE - F# Make
.fake/

# JetBrains Rider
.idea/
*.sln.iml

# CodeRush
.cr/

# Python Tools for Visual Studio (PTVS)
__pycache__/
*.pyc

# Cake - Uncomment if you are using it
# tools/**
# !tools/packages.config

# Telerik's JustMock configuration file
*.jmconfig

# BizTalk build output
*.btp.cs
*.btm.cs
*.odx.cs
*.xsd.cs
```

Comment: I think it is Git's standard behavior to treat new files as being untracked, until you manually add them.

Comment: We can only guess if you don't include the .gitignore or more information here.

Comment: @Esko it took me a while, but the git file is there. Sorry for the delay

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean by "automatically ignored"? Where do you see it being ignored (as opposed to untracked as @TimBiegeleisen indicated)? What is the output of `git status`?

Comment: @bto, the new file's Version Control Status Icon is a red circle (with a rectangle in the middle), which if hovered over will show the word "Ignored". In addition, if I right click on the file I see the option "Add Ignored File to Source Control"

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Visual Studio is supposed to add the file to source control automatically, that is how it behaves in all projects(even within the same solution) except for this one.

Comment: I have this silly problem off and on. I don't know what triggers it. Functions correctly for me at work, doesn't work at home for some reason or another. I have to keep manually adding the files that are automatically ignored. I checked my ignore file, nothing in there to indicate why this is happening. I've restarted VS and that helps sometimes. Can't help but notice this happened after a recent upgrade. I use git bash most of the time for this exact reason.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Eureka!!. My project name was matching the pattern *.sap on the .gitignore file, so all new files on that project would automatically be ignored. I removed the *.sap pattern from the .gitignore file and now everything works as expected.

Comment: I am working on a project with SAP concur. 
I was scratching my head, then I saw this answer. This was my issue. Project name ended in .SAP

Answer (score 2):

It happens form time to time. Just close and reopen Visual Studio.

Because of this inconsistency (I think it's a bug) I also look for untracked files in another "visual" git app (SourceTree) to make sure that nothing is left behind inside some directory.

Comment: In my case it never goes away, even restarting VS

Answer (score 0):

I tested your `.gitignore` file locally, and it works fine. My best guess is that you need to stage your files. I think you are confusing ignored files with untracked files.

Git is seperated into three "directories". When you "track" a file it means that changes between these three directories are kept. Ignored files are not tracked.

**Working Directory**
The working directory is basically what is on your hard drive. Git will track differences on files and folders between the working directory and the staging area. Everything that is *untracked* is in the working directory. And every change to a tracked file is contained in the working directory.

**Staging area**
Whenever you "stage" something (by using `git add`) you stage the changes. This means that you copy the changes from the working directory to the staging area. When you stage a file or folder, the files are kept in the working directory (i.e. the harddrive), but copied to the staging area as well.

The staging area a sort of middle ground between a commit and an untracked file. You need to stage your files before you can commit them.

**Local Branch**
When you commit something you take whatever is currently *staged*, and make a *commit*, and append that commit to the current branch. This will also remove the changeset from the stagin area.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Andersnk, however, the flow is different when using Visual Studio. Normally in VS a new file will be automatically tracked and included in source control (I assume VS will stage it automatically), leaving me with just the last step of committing it.

Comment: Visual studio will *not* track files automatically, nor stage them unless you install a plugin that does that for you.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio's Team Explorer and haven't installed any plugin. I've used VS and GIT like this for more than a year and new files always show in the "Changes" section ready to be commited. This is what I mean by them being tracked automatically. Whatever commands VS executes behind scenes I do not know.

Comment: Well, your plugin might be broken. It's not your `.gitignore` file thats broken.